# Arabic meta tags

Tags: php, html, yii, meta-tags

I am trying to show an Arabic meta tags, but when ever I load the page, and I view the source it shows some garbage.

This is my config.php file

```
define("GAMES_META_DESCRIPTION",   "بيسبي");
```

and this is my header file

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="ar" xml:lang="ar">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1256">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="ar-sy">
<meta name="description" content="<?=htmlentities($meta_description);?>">
</head>
```

any help with be rewarded with a cookie :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try using plain arabic characters instead of using a function
e.g
meta name="description" content="بيسب"

probably the problem is in your function itself not encoding.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that both your PHP and your header files are the same encoding. Preferably UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

ok I don't know for what you need meta description? it is not useful. Anyway I recommend use UTF8. file have to be saved as utf8 and meta:

```
<meta http-equiv='content-Type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8'/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree. Use:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

With double quotes and a space before `/>` (I know I'm picky, but that's as far as I know the standard way to do it.)

One upside with using UTF-8 is that you almost never have to replace special characters, like the Swedish letter å, with HTML entites (in the case of å, `&aring;`).

Also, I disagree with the comment above that meta descriptions aren't useful. On the contrary, I find meta descriptions very useful, mainly because they appear often enough in results from google searches.

Answer (score 0):

Try to open output buffering in the top of the page before any html

```
<?php ob_start(); ?>
```

and in the bottom end of your code

```
<?php ob_end_flush(); ?>
```

it will make cookie work with meta.

Output buffering is very helpful with

```
header("location:anyPage.php")
```